# rails 3.2 Scope with Optional Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following scope for finding a product that belongs to a specific client.

```
scope :client, lambda {|client| where("client_id = ?", client) }
```

and can be called by

```
Product.client(parameter)
```

Is there any way I can declare my scope to return all products if a client id is not given?  Is this a situation where a scope shouldn't be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something other than a scope, since you really want to switch between the two cases (with/without a client id specified) and respond differently. How about this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.by_client(client)
    if client
      where(client_id: client)
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

This code will always return something like the output of `scope`, so you can chain with it etc.

Note that this also tidies up the code and doesn't require a particular scope. And make sure you don't actually mean to have `has_many :clients` for the `Product` anyway...

Comment: I'm getting a too few arguments error if a client_id is not provided. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should call it with a `client`, even if the `client` is `nil`. If you are trying to call it as `Product.by_client()` with no argument, just use the `Product.all` version in that code instead!

Comment: You could adjust the method to be `self.by_client(client=nil)` so that you don't need to specify a `client`, but that seems silly to me because you would end up having an `if` statement somewhere else in your code to decide whether to pass a `client` or not. If you're doing that, just call the version you want in that code.

Answer (score 7):

It can work OK with scopes

```
scope :client, lambda {|client =  nil| where("client_id = ?", client) unless client.nil? }
```